# Is BlackBerry supported by Titanium SDK?

Tags: blackberry, titanium, titanium-mobile

can anyone please let me know does is Blackberry supported by Titanium SDK or not. Actually i gone through many sites. I followed the procedure of installing it but after installation i can't find any BB plugins in Titanium. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it is only for paid users, who can access the beta.

However, they have announced ( http://thinkmobile.appcelerator.com/press-releases/bid/142950/Appcelerator-s-300-000-Worldwide-Developers-to-Gain-Application-Support-on-Blackberry-10-Platform ) they will be supporting blackberry 10. But you'll have to wait for it.

Other than this, no support for blackberry.

Answer (score 1):

I think they provide paid support for it and is still in beta for blackberry.

Comment: Is there any other way that unpaid people can access blackberry in Titanium and "beta" means is it blackberry beta version.....

Comment: sorry can't help in that. I did do research some time back and at the end was only able to conclude that.. it is something in beta now...

Comment: @JigarTank it is near about after one year can i access blackberry in titanium at this time...because i already do all the installing things but i have same issue...which you have faced..i am using free version of it